# GooglePlus OWIN Storing multiple claims cause AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() to return null

Tags: asp.net, google-plus, owin

I have an issue in my app where AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() returns null after the first successful call AND when it becomes authenticated as I record two claims(access token and refresh token). If I record just the access token, life seems to be good and the AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() continues to return a non-null LoginInfo payload. If I record any other random types of claims, like "test", "foo" "wacka wacka" it also still works.

So the code where I frame up the GooglePlus options looks as follows

```
var googleOptions = new GooglePlusAuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = clientId,
    ClientSecret = clientSecret,
    RequestOfflineAccess = true,
    Provider = new GooglePlusAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnAuthenticated = async context =>
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(GooglePlusAccessTokenClaimType, context.AccessToken));
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:tokens:Test", "Test"));
                //context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(GooglePlusRefreshTokenClaimType, context.RefreshToken));
            }
        }
};

googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me");
googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds");
googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly");
googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");
```

This first line in the method is the one that horribly returns null

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
```

I've definitely gone up and down Google and StackOverflow, Microsoft's various pages and seen the suggestion to do

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    Session["dummy"] = "dummy";
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

or add the following to the web.config

```
<location path="signin-googleplus">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Unfortunately, non of it is working. If saving the refresh token is not best practices as well, I'm very opening to knowing what is.

Much appreciation in advance!